# RXJava - onBackpressureBuffer + multiple observers not working

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I have an `Observable` and subscribe to it. I need to not miss any emitted result, so I use `onBackpressureBuffer` like following:

```
Observable<Data> observable = observable.onBackpressureBuffer();
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
{
    observable 
        .subscribeOn(HandlerScheduler.from(dataManager.getBackgroundHandler()))
        .observeOn(HandlerScheduler.from(dataManager.getBackgroundHandler()))
        .subscribe(new MeasuringSubscriber(...));
}
// Here is the real observer that I need in my app
observable
        .subscribeOn(HandlerScheduler.from(dataManager.getBackgroundHandler()))
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(new Observer<Data>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(Data data) {

            }
        });
```

The `MeasuringSubscriber` is a custom subscriber that just logs how long a task needs, that's all.

**Problem**

If I add the `MeasuringSubscriber`, the subscribers do not work anymore and never emit a result. Why? And how can I make that working?

**EDIT - NEW PROBLEM**

Currently it's working, but the MeasuringSubscriber is somehow blocking, meaning, first all items are emitted one by one to the `MeasuringSubscriber` and only afterwards all items are emitted one by one to the main subscriber... Any ideas what could cause that?

I have a solution for that - I can extend my main observalbe from the `MeasuringObservable` - but I rather would like to know why this happens and how to avoid this...

I tried using `publish` + `connect`, but still it does emit all items to the first subscriber before emitting them to the second one...

Comment: What's 'res' you are subscribing in debug config ?

Comment: Forgot to replace that, it's the `observable`... Already corrected that...

Comment: If your observable is an actual stream it may already be subscribed to and you can not subscribe to it twice. Consider using `Observable.share()` or something similar that's available in rx for android.

Comment: It's no stream nor is anyone subscriber to it before, it's only a simple functional observable that iterates over a list and calculates some things... Currently it's working, but the `MeasuringSubscriber` is somehow blocking, meaning, first all items are emitted one by one to the `MeasuringSubscriber` and only afterwards all items are emitted one by one to the main subscriber... Any idea what could cause that?

Comment: PS: I tried using `publish` + `connect`, but still it does emit all items to the first subscriber before emitting them to the second one...

Comment: When do you call connect ? It should be called after the second subscribe.